# É possível fazer comunicação Cliente-Servidor em tempo real via HTTP?

Tags: http, websocket

Usando *TCP sockets* eu consigo colocar um aplicativo servidor em *listening* e fazer clientes conectar e aguardar por requisições tanto no servidor, quanto no cliente, tendo a possibilidade do servidor enviar informações para TODOS os clientes conectados sem qualquer requisição por parte do cliente. Para resumir isso, posso usar um *MMORPG* por exemplo.

### A dúvida:

É possível fazer o mesmo tipo de comunicação em TEMPO REAL utilizando `HTTP`? Ou isso seria possível apenas com *WebSockets*? Para ser mais claro: seria possível fazer um *MMORPG* utilizando `HTTP`, onde clientes `HTTP` (um browser por exemplo, ou algum `HTTP` client como a biblioteca *HttpClient* do .Net) conectam  no servidor e faça uma comunicação igual no protocolo TCP? Sendo o servidor HTTP capaz de enviar informações para todos os clientes conectados?

### Meu objetivo:

Criar um servidor ÚNICO, que fique em *listening* em algum protocolo que ainda não defini (por isso a dúvida) onde será responsável por responder requisições dos clientes e enviar em TEMPO REAL informações para todos ou X clientes de várias plataformas, como Android, iOS, desktop(*browser*). Como se fosse um chat em grupo do Facebook ou WhatsApp.

OBS: Seria muito esclarecedor pra mim como é o funcionamento (comunicação Client-Server) do chat do Facebook e Whatsapp.

Comment: ai vai alguns dados do whatsapp http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/2/26/the-whatsapp-architecture-facebook-bought-for-19-billion.html

Comment: Fala Gustavo, estava gerando uma pergunta como essa e achei a sua, estou no mesmo objetivo e em um futuro próximo que sabe lançar um MMORPG pois gosto muita dessa área Web e games! Minha pergunte é se você desenvolveu o game para navegadores, se sim qual, e questões de segurança nos nevegadores?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A minha única experiência com tempo real foi apenas com os tutoriais do ***[Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)***, e eu recomendo que você dê uma olhada - é bastante impressionante. Em minutos você monta uma aplicação básica com clientes HTTP (*browsers*) compartilhando dados em tempo real. Recomendo!

---

Eu tenho pouco experiência, mas Phil Leggetter é um dos *experts* nessa área, e [no seu *blog*](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/) ele publica regularmente sobre o assunto. A imagem abaixo é do seu *post* entitulado "[Choosing your Realtime Web App Tech Stack](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2013/12/09/choosing-realtime-web-app-tech-stack.html)"

[image: realtime services]

Além do [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/), que eu já conhecia, ele menciona [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/), [SocketStream](http://www.socketstream.org/) e [DerbyJS](http://derbyjs.com/) como "*Realtime Frameworks*" (ele diferencia o Meteor frisando que não é apenas um *framework* mas uma *platform* completa).

Mas o cara é fera! Confira:

- [History, Background, Benefits & Use Cases of Realtime](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2013/10/28/history-background-benefits-use-cases-realtime.html) (part 1 of 3)
- [Fundamentals of the Realtime Web & Realtime Web Functionality](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2013/10/31/fundamentals-realtime-web-realtime-web-functionality.html) (part 2 of 3)
- [Choosing your Realtime Web App Tech Stack](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2013/12/09/choosing-realtime-web-app-tech-stack.html) (part 3 of 3)
- [10 Realtime Web Technology Predictions for 2014](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2014/02/24/10-realtime-web-technology-predictions-for-2014.html)

De uma [longa lista de tecnologias de suporte à construção de aplicações em tempo real](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide), ele destaca:

#### [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)

> Uma biblioteca em Node.js com muitos ports para outras linguagens.

#### [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/)

> Faye é uma solução que oferece uma simples abstração *pub/sub* com
>   suporte *fallback* completo. Isto significa que irá servir à maioria
>   das necessidades de uma aplicação em tempo real, e irá funcionar em
>   99% dos *browsers* e ambientes de rede.
>
> Outra vantagem do Faye é que está disponível em Ruby e Node.js, e
>   muita consideração foi dada à segurança. Tudo o que você precisa para
>   construir uma aplicação em tempo real pronta para entrar em produção.

#### [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)

> Se você quiser trabalhar próximo aos fundamentos de WebSockets no
>   cliente, mas também se beneficiar com mecanismos de *fallback*, então
>   SockJS é uma boa escolha. SockJS providencia um "emulador JavaScript
>   de cliente WebSocket" e tem servidores disponíveis em Node.js, Erland,
>   Python/Tornado, Python/Twisted e Java. Servidores em Ruby, Perl, Go e
>   Haskell em desenvolvimento.

#### [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)

> SignalR é uma solução de código aberto para ASP.NET

Taí... espero ter colaborado com essas referências. Experimente o [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) e... se não servir, experimente o resto. ;-) Boa sorte!

Comment: Achei este artigo hoje, é um tutorial do Meteor: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/13/build-app-45-minutes-meteor (construa uma aplicação Meteor em 45 minutos)

Answer (score 6):

### Tecnologia Push (Ajax Push)

**1. Usando conexão sem "fim"**

Nessa técnica você pode usar Ajax deixando ele perene com o servidor, quando receber a informação deve trata-la e mostrar no browser. Aqui o XMLHttpRequest deve ter o timeout configurada para um tempo infinito e o readyState vai ficar sempre 3 (recebendo). O problema aqui é que o servidor não tem como controlar o que acontece "fora" do browser se a conexão cair será necessário recarregar a página.

**2. Usando pool de conexão**

Essa é bem usada hoje, aqui você mantem uma conexão XMLHttpRequest no browser, esperando resposta do servidor, mas renova de tempo em tempo, o servidor consegue controlar a conexão, o javascript (Ajax) deve abrir sempre uma conexão quando essa for "terminada". De uma olhada em [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/bosh/)

**3. Usando Flash XMLSocket**

Você pode usar o XMLSocket do flash fazendo interação com o javascript dessa maneira você conseguiria manter uma conexão ativa com o servidor visto que o XMLSocket implementa situações que não estão presente no XMLHttpRequest do javascript.

### Server-side

O problema todo está aqui, o servidor tem que suportar as conexões por longos tempos eu conheço o [cometd](http://cometd.org/) que pode ser estudado para essas implementações.

Answer (score 4):

É possível sim fazer uma comunicação em tempo real com o servidor.

Você citou algo que já me permitir trazer pra você um exemplo prático (.NET)

Na tecnologia .NET foi criado um serviço de tempo real chamado [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr), com ele você consegue trabalhar em tempo real. No link, na parte ao lado em baixo disponibiliza vários links pela Pluralsight com explicações do funcionamento do SignalR.

Hoje na empresa em que trabalho, estamos estudando essa tecnologia para por em prática em alguns projetos. Vale a pena dar uma conferida.

Creio que irá lhe atender muito bem.

Abraços

Comment: Realmente, o SignalR é perfeito para essa tarefa. Além de ter amplo suporte, e de ser desenvolvido pela Microsoft.

Comment: É possível instalar o SignalR via nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.signalr

Answer (score 0):

Outra opção ao SignalR, que possui alguns inconvenientes, tal como o de ele não usar `WebSockets` caso o servidor não esteja usando o IIS-8, é o [xsockets](http://xsockets.net/)... que cria conexões no lado do servidor de forma independe do IIS.