# Aparecer atualização igual ao facebook, na hora

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho que fazer um sistema aonde o usuário envia mensagem e aquele que recebe, vê o número 1 do lado do menu, na hora que recebe a mensagem. Tipo o facebook, quando você recebe uma notificação fica o número 1 do lado do globo. Queria saber se alguém tem noção de como fazer isso, estava pensando em fazer utilizando a função `setTimeOut` do *jQuery* e fazer ele ficar atualizando de 2 em 2 segundos para verificar algo novo relativo ao usuário que recebeu.

Comment: Pergunta que pode ajudar com alguns conceitos sobre websocket e push: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9067/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-fazer-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-cliente-servidor-em-tempo-real-via-http

Comment: Correção setTimeout não é do jQuery, e sim nativo do javascript, você pode considerar usar o $.ajax para verificar se há novas mensagens. Sobre o tempo 2 segundos acho que é um tempo muito curto, e pode causar problemas em relação a performance do servidor. A Amazon por exemplo efetua suas atualizações ajax a cada 20 segundos se eu não me engano.

Comment: @HiagoSouza você considera a opção de mesclar a função **setTimeOut** com **$.ajax()** boa para fazer o que necessito?

Comment: Sim claro, no $.ajax você pode declarar o dataType como script e enviar de retorno uma função jquery para alterar o seu DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Dá uma olhada em websockets. 
Acho que seria a melhor solução pra esses sistemas que precisam manter conexão com o servidor em real-time.

jQuery pra conexão com o backend: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-websocket/

Pra responder o socket: http://socketo.me/

Comment: Dei uma visualizada e procurei exemplos, mas a maioria fala sobre chat ou algo que tem que clicar para mostrar em real-time, só que os exemplos mostra a pessoa que enviou recebendo em real-time e eu precisava de que uma pessoa manda e outra recebe em real-time, igual ao facebook.

Answer (score -3):

Recomendo que veja padrões css como bootstrap ou facebook. Eu já fiz isso usando bootstrap. Algo como selecionar total das mensagens de XXX e colocar o resultado na tag de modo que fiquei igual ao face.

Uma boa dica.

http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/facebook

Comment: Sabe algo com jQuery/Javascript ?!

Comment: Desculpa mais você leu a pergunta?