# Como fazer com que o Jquery rode em todas as páginas simultaneamente

Tags: php, jquery

Por exemplo: com 2 páginas do facebook abertas, abra alguma conversa com algum amigo em 1 das páginas, vá na 2 página e verá que a janela está aberta lá também, como isto é possível? Como é feito?

***USO PHP/JQUERY***

Comment: Ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33792/aparecer-atualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-igual-ao-facebook-na-hora

Comment: sim, mas não é a questão do tempo real (websockets, ou outros) e sim, como um elemento foi criado com o "append" por exemplo, em 1 página e na outra página a janelinha está lá, aberta..

Comment: Cada página troca informação separadamente com o servidor, e atualiza seu conteúdo de acordo com o que o servidor responde.

Comment: Oh, sim claro como não havia pensado nisto, uma vez que o facebook é em tempo real, ele abrirá na hora as atualizações de cada perfil e janelas de chat abertas, obrigado bfavaretto!

Comment: havia pensado que isto era uma função do jquery, fazer um append em todas as páginas :S

Comment: Isso é sim função do jQuery (na verdade, do JavaScript, com ou sem jQuery), mas cada página faz isso separadamente. Elas não se comunicam entre si, cada uma se comunica com o servidor.