# Temporizador Javascript

Tags: javascript

Bom o que eu queria era fazer um temporizador de 60 segundos.

Que funcionasse da seguinte forma:
Contasse 60 segundos de forma decrescente 60,59,58, 57, etc... e quando chegasse ao 0, pausasse no 0 durante 3 segundos, e recomeçava tudo de novo 60,59, 58 etc...

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado antes de mais.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes ter um `setInterval` permanente e ir "gerindo o tráfego" de flags/contadores para fazer o que quiseres.

Por exemplo:

```
var contador = 60;
var espera;
setInterval(function() {
    contador--;

    if (contador > 0) return reporter(contador + ' segundos'); // aqui é o caso ativo
    if (contador == 0) espera = 3;

    reporter('à espera ' + espera + ' segundos'); // aqui é o caso de espera
    if (contador < 0) espera--;
    if (espera == 0) contador = 60;

}, 1000);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9har0tud/

```js
var reporter = function(report) {
    document.body.innerHTML = report;
}
var contador = 60;
var espera;
setInterval(function() {
    contador--;

    if (contador > 0) return reporter(contador + ' segundos');
    if (contador == 0) espera = 3;
    
    reporter('à espera ' + espera + ' segundos');
    if (contador < 0) espera--;
    if (espera == 0) contador = 60;

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Faltou a função reporter no seu código.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo não coloquei porque não é importante para a pergunta/resposta, mas está no jsFiddle. No fundo em vez dessa função pode ser o que o AP quiser, ou seja código que corre quando as condições se verificarem.

Comment: Entendi Sérgio, só comentei pois as vezes a pessoa que vê sua resposta é tão leiga a ponto de testar o seu código e não saber o por que de não funcionar.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo bem visto. Juntei um exemplo aqui também, com tudo.

Answer (score 6):

Utilize um conjunto de `setInterval()` com `setTimeout()`:

```js
var temporizador = document.getElementById('temporizador');

var ativerIntervalo = function() {
  temporizador.innerHTML = 60;
  var intervalo = setInterval(function() {
    var novoValor = parseInt(temporizador.innerHTML, 10) - 1;
    temporizador.innerHTML = novoValor;

    if (novoValor === 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalo);
      setTimeout(ativerIntervalo, 3000);
    }
  }, 1000);
};
ativerIntervalo();
```

```html
<p>Temporizador: <span id="temporizador">60</span></p>
```

`setInterval()` para fazer seu contador descer de 60 até 0, e `setTimeout()` para esperar 3 segundos antes de fazer tudo denovo.

Comment: Não está a funcionar o código.

Comment: @Gonçalo estranho, estou executando o código aqui no SO e está funcionando como deveria. O contador começa em 60, decrementa até 0, 1 por segundo, e fica 3 segundos parado no 0. Depois repete o processo eternamente.

Comment: Pode-me enviar o código completo.

Comment: Já consegui, tinha colocado o <p>Temporizador: <span id="temporizador">60</span></p> por baixo.

Comment: Diga-me uma coisa qual é a variavel que pega o tempo, em tempo real?

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua pergunta. `novoValor` é a variável que vai, a cada segundo, ter o valor atual do contador. Quando o temporizador estiver em `45`, `novoValor` vai ser igual a `45`.

Comment: E diga-me uma coisa, tem como o temporizador ser geral, ou seja ser para todos, pq quando eu dou f5, o temporizador volta a 60 segundos.

Comment: Ou seja quando for 45 segundo para mim, seja para outra pessoa q esteja na pagina ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Hum, até tem, mas vai complicar um pouco. Daqui a pouco atualizo minha resposta para refletir essa sua ideia.

Comment: Certo, obrigado.

Comment: Nem, que seja necessário ficar com o navegador ligado 24 horas.

Comment: @Gonçalo na verdade vou deixar isso de fora da resposta, porque não é o escopo da pergunta, e não é trivial dar um exemplo. O que você precisa nesse caso é de *realtime communication*. Dê uma lida [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9067/41113).

Comment: Se eu editar a pergunta, pode responder na resposta?

Answer (score 0):

exemplo usando apenas o setTimout e considerando que você tenha um elemento com id="contador" 
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5999yec6/)

```
function contar(numeroAtual) {
    document.getElementById('contador').textContent = numeroAtual;
    if (numeroAtual === 0) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        contar(60);
    }, 3000);
  } else {
    numeroAtual--;
    setTimeout(function(){
        contar(numeroAtual);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

contar(0);
```